# Target link Eigen library on Clion fails

Tags: c++, eigen, clion

I am trying to link eigen to my project on clion, but the following error is printed:

This is my cmakelist file with all the attempts to link the library:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(planner_standalone_grasp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O0")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-diagnostics-color")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")

# find all cpp files in currect directory (where CMakeLists.txt is)
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "./src/*.cpp")


include_directories(src)


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp ${SOURCE_FILES})


set(EXE_LIBS
    ctop_common
    ctop_log
    ctop_util

    eigen
    crl
    crl-algorithm
    crl-loader
    crl-tsplib
    yaml-cpp
)


target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC lib/comrob/lib/)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ctop/common/cmake-build-debug/)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ctop/log/cmake-build-debug/)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ctop/util/cmake-build-debug/)


set(EIGEN_DIR "/usr/local/include/Eigen/")
include_directories(${EIGEN_DIR})


find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} Eigen3::Eigen)

target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC lib/eigen/Eigen/)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC /usr/local/include/Eigen/)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/)


target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${EXE_LIBS})
```

All other libraries in the project are successfully linked except Eigen - This is the error message:

```
[6/6] Linking CXX executable planner_standalone_grasp
FAILED: planner_standalone_grasp 
: && /usr/bin/c++ -O0 -fno-diagnostics-color -std=c++17 -g -rdynamic CMakeFiles/planner_standalone_grasp.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/planner_standalone_grasp.dir/src/Grasp.cpp.o CMakeFiles/planner_standalone_grasp.dir/src/WallEdge.cpp.o CMakeFiles/planner_standalone_grasp.dir/src/WallGraph.cpp.o CMakeFiles/planner_standalone_grasp.dir/src/pt2eigen.cpp.o -o planner_standalone_grasp -L/home/sim/CLionProjects/Test/lib/comrob/lib   -L/home/sim/CLionProjects/Test/ctop/common/cmake-build-debug   -L/home/sim/CLionProjects/Test/ctop/log/cmake-build-debug   -L/home/sim/CLionProjects/Test/ctop/util/cmake-build-debug   -L/home/sim/CLionProjects/Test/lib/eigen/Eigen   -L/usr/local/include/Eigen   -L/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen -Wl,-rpath,/home/sim/CLionProjects/Test/lib/comrob/lib:/home/sim/CLionProjects/Test/ctop/common/cmake-build-debug:/home/sim/CLionProjects/Test/ctop/log/cmake-build-debug:/home/sim/CLionProjects/Test/ctop/util/cmake-build-debug:/home/sim/CLionProjects/Test/lib/eigen/Eigen:/usr/local/include/Eigen:/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen  -lctop_common  -lctop_log  -lctop_util  -leigen  -lcrl  -lcrl-algorithm  -lcrl-loader  -lcrl-tsplib  -lyaml-cpp && :
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -leigen
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: There should not be anything to link, just include the headers during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience there is two possible causes for this issue:

1. there is no library named libeigen. in the provided directories (the ones in target_link_directories). Perhaps the path is wrong?
   You should know that usually library files are not located in the include directories of a repository...
2. there is a library named as such, though it was compiled for the wrong platform... i.e. a library compiled for linux cannot be linked if you are making an executable for windows. Usually you can find the source code and compile it yourself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As per Installation instructions for Eigen

Eigen consists only of header files, hence there is nothing to compile
before you can use it. Moreover, these header files do not depend on your
platform, they are the same for everybody.

I installed Eigen using CMake

Created directory 'source_dir' (where this INSTALL file is).
Before starting, create another directory which we will call 'build_dir'.
then i:
  cd build_dir
  cmake source_dir
  make install

Comment: Now eigen installation files are found under usr/local/include/Eigen and usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen and also in my existing project -- Build files have been written to: /home/sim/CLionProjects/Test/lib/eigen/build_dir

Comment: Hmmm if Eigen is header only, you should not try to link against it ;) Can you try removing eigen from set(EXE_LIBS ...)?

Comment: I don't think you will be needing those target_link_directories for Eigen either as they specify paths to try and look for libraries...